# Admin user folder is invisible within application file browsers

Tags: macos

The admin user's folder on my mac is not visible from within application file browsers despite being visible in finder and accessible via the favourites sidebar.

As some applications have their own file dialog without favourites I cannot access the admin folder on those occasions.

Comment: Are you sure you're browsing in the correct location? What does `ls -lao /Users` show?

Comment: Yes because the other users show up, that command lists all the folders.

Comment: The `-o` flag should show any flags present on the directory — are there any flags? Can you see the Admin user folder from a new user account?

Comment: this is the line for the admin user drwxr-xr-x@ 59 lewis    2006  7 Dec 17:35 lewis